# Uploading video to facebook via JS SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

To make a long story short - I'm trying to upload an mp4 to facebook via the Javascript SDK.  According to the documentation I should be able to do this:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/videos",
    "POST",
    {
        "source": "{video-data}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

However - no matter what  I pass through as a source I keep getting back an error object that says "(#353) You must select a video file to upload."  Is there something missing from this method that is causing this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find the solution?